# Livereload a local url using Grunt watch

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I'm developing a small HTML/JS/SASS project without an backend/server and I'm trying to get Livereloading to work.

In my grunt.initConfig I have:

```
options: {
  livereload: true,
},
```

But in Chrome I can't activate the Liverload plugin on a local html file.

> file:///C:/Users/alucardu/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202015/Projects/JS-demo/JS-demo/index.html

Is this possible to do or do I need to run a server?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Grunt has something for this called `connect` > https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect

When I installed it I added this to my gruntFile:

```
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                keepalive: true,
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: 8080,
                base: ''
            }
        }
    },
```

And now I can run a local static server :)